# Finding the derivative of $f(x) = \frac{8}{\sqrt{x -2}}$ using first principles.

Tags: calculus, derivatives

How would you go about determining the derivative of ( $f(x) = \frac{8}{\sqrt{x -2}}$ ) using the limit definition of the derivative 
(i.e. $\lim\limits_{h\to 0} = \frac{f(x+h) - f(x)}{h}$) as opposed to just applying the chain rule. So I'm thinking this counts as an algebra question but can't find too many examples dealing with simplification of polynomial expressions with fractional exponents. 
I got as far as, 
$\frac {1}{h}  (\frac{8}{\sqrt{x+h-2}} - \frac{8}{\sqrt{x-2}})$
In case I'm not using correct terminology or being unclear, what I mean is, can one algebraically eliminate the $h$ from the denominator in the above expression to take the value of the limit?

Comment: When writing math enclose expression by dollar-signs, i.e. `$math$`, and use `$\sqrt{}$`.

Comment: If I understood you correctly your question can be better summarized by "Find the derivative of $x\mapsto \frac 8{\sqrt{x-2}}$ by first principles".

Comment: Yes i suppose that would be the way to say it, which I think comes down to an algebra question right?

Comment: @Arthur I believe this probably really is just an arithmetic problem when it comes down to it. I think on NA they call it algebra. Britzkopf: I would put everything under the same denominator and then multiply by $\dfrac{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x-h+2}}{\sqrt{x-2}+\sqrt{x-h+2}}$. Things seem to cancel out nicely, but I didn't check.

Comment: @Arthur, in that case i have a deeper misunderstanding because i thought the point was to massage the expression until you get the h out of the denominator and can then make it 0 and evaluate.

Comment: I just found this thread which gives the solution for which i was looking.
http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/207484/derivative-of-frac1-sqrtx5?rq=1
I'm fairly new to stack exchange, am i obliged to delete this question since its covered in the one linked to?

Comment: @britzkopf The best thing you can do is write an answer yourself completing the details.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hint: For $x>2$ and any non-zero $h$ such that $x+h>2$:

$$\frac {1}{h}  \left(\frac{8}{\sqrt{x+h-2}} - \frac{8}{\sqrt{x-2}}\right)$$

$$ =  \frac {1}{h}  \frac{8(\sqrt{x-2} - \sqrt{x+h-2})}{\sqrt{x+h-2}\sqrt{x-2}} $$

$$ =   \frac {1}{h}  \frac{8[(x-2) - (x+h-2)]}{\sqrt{x+h-2}\sqrt{x-2}(\sqrt{x-2} + \sqrt{x+h-2})} $$

$$ = -\frac{8}{\sqrt{x+h-2}\sqrt{x-2}(\sqrt{x-2} + \sqrt{x+h-2})}. $$

When $h$ approaches $0$, the last fraction approaches:
$$  -\frac{4}{(x-2)\sqrt{x-2}} $$

Comment: Thanks. I'm in need of algebra remediation.